# Calc position to draw a circle

Tags: javascript, math, lua, rect

I have to draw 2 circles where I give the draw function the center point of each circle and the x, y.

I first circle is static, will be on the same x and y.
The second circle is smaller, and will follow the mouse position, but it's center point can't go outside the First circle.

Considering that I have this variables:
Circle1.x, Circle1.y, Circle.radius
Mouse.x, Mouse.y

How can I get the x and y for the circle2?

Here is a pick to show What I need:
[image: pic]
Black : Circle1
Red : Circle2
Green : Mouse

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the center of the circle from the mouse position. This results into a vector (dx,dy) pointing from the center of the circle to the mouse position. This vectors length should be equal or smaller than the circles radius. If the length is smaller than the radius of the circle: the mouse position is within the circle and stays the same, If the length is larger than the radius of the circle: normalize the vector and multiply it with the radius, adding the resulting vector to the center of the circle will result in the new position.

Psuedo code:

```
dx = Mouse.x-Circle1.x
dy = Mouse.y-Circle1.y

length = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)

if (length > Circle.radius)
  ratio = Circle1.radius/length
  Circle2.x = Circle1.x + dx*ratio
  Circle2.y = Circle1.y + dy*ratio
else
  Circle2.x = Mouse.x
  Circle2.y = Mouse.y
end
```